# Pass arrays to solidity's function from truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, metamask, truffle-contract

I am getting `ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code` in metamask when calling `addBet` function from truffle. The function works without any errors when called from remix. The function also works from truffle if I change the code and pass individual values instead of arrays. Is it really possible to pass arrays to a solidity function from truffle?

In browser console I see this

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":779020742217,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["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"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object] 
uncaught exception: Object
```

Betting.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Betting {

    struct Bet{
        uint betId;
        string question;
        BetStatus betStatus;
        mapping(uint => MoneyLineDatum) moneyLineData;
        uint lengthMoneyLineData;
    }

    struct MoneyLineDatum{
        string option;
        int value; 
    }

    address public owner = msg.sender;

    mapping(uint => Bet) public bets;
    uint public lengthBets;
    enum BetStatus {Open, Closed}

    constructor() public{
        string[2] memory options = ["Gator", "Miami"];
        int[2] memory values = [int(200), -100];
        addBet("Gator vs Miami", options, values);

        options = ["Gator", "Georgia"];
        values = [int(200), -150];
        addBet("Gator vs Georgia", options, values);
    }

    modifier onlyBy(address account){
        require(msg.sender == account, "Unauthorised Access");
        _;
    }

    function addNewEmptyBet() public{
        Bet memory bet;
        bets[lengthBets] = bet;
    }

    function addBet(string memory question, string[2] memory options, int[2] memory values) public onlyBy(owner){
        addNewEmptyBet();
        Bet storage bet = bets[lengthBets];
        bet.betId = lengthBets;
        bet.question = question;
        bet.betStatus = BetStatus.Open;
        lengthBets+=1;
        for(uint i=0; i<options.length; i++){
            bet.moneyLineData[i] = MoneyLineDatum(options[i], values[i]);
        }
        bet.lengthMoneyLineData+=options.length;
    }

    function getLengthMoneyLineData(uint betId) public view returns(uint){
        return bets[betId].lengthMoneyLineData;
    }

    function getMoneyLineData(uint betId, uint idx) public view returns(string memory, int){
        MoneyLineDatum storage moneyLineDatum = bets[betId].moneyLineData[idx];
        return (moneyLineDatum.option, moneyLineDatum.value);
    }
}
```

Snippet from app.js

```
App.contracts.Betting.deployed().then(function(_instance){
    return _instance.addBet(question, options, values, {from: App.account});
}).then(function(){
    console.log("Bet has been added");          
});
```

`options` and `values` are arrays each of size 2 with datatypes `string[]` and `int[]` respectively

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. Get rid of `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`
2. Replace every occurrence of `string` with `bytes32`
3. Replace every occurrence of `bytes32 memory` with `bytes32`
4. Replace every occurrence of `"Gator"` with `bytes32("Gator")`
5. Replace every occurrence of `"Miami"` with `bytes32("Miami")`
6. Replace every occurrence of `"Georgia"` with `bytes32("Georgia")`
7. Replace every occurrence of `"Gator vs Miami"` with `bytes32("Gator vs Miami")`
8. Replace every occurrence of `"Gator vs Georgia"` with `bytes32("Gator vs Georgia")`
9. In your Truffle test, convert each string `x` to:

   - `web3.fromAscii(x)` if you're on Truffle v4.x (which relies on Web3 v0.x) or earlier
   - `web3.utils.asciiToHex(x)` if you're on Truffle v5.x (which relies on Web3 v1.x) or later

A few notes on your contract's code:

- It seems that each one of your mappings is used as if it was an array; so you should probably use arrays instead (for good practice, as well as for gas-cost efficiency)
- The `onlyBy` modifier doesn't need to take `account` as input argument; instead, it can compare the value of `msg.sender` directly to the value of `owner`

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed solution. I was stuck at this since 3 days. It works now. I am not using array because later I do want to access things by key. onlyBy is kind of a general function for restricting access so I have kept the address parameter.